# Node postgresql insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a services table, a service_categories table, a service_service_categories table. Services and service_categories are a many to many relationship, and the other is the junction table.

I am using node js for my backend. I would like to insert a new service AND and new service_service_category row (for each id in returned category ids array) within a single query in node post request.
The service_categories table will be populated already.
So I am informed that it is acheivable by doing multiple inserts with returns, and using the returned values in the next insert, but I can't seem to find how this would be done in practice.
My idea is to store the category_ids in a column on my services table and return that from the insert on the services table. This code works when the column is singular integer type(ie category_id):

```
const newService = await pool.query(
      `
      with ins1 AS
      (
       INSERT INTO services (name,summary,category_id)
           VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING service_id, category_id
      ),
      ins2 AS
      (
       INSERT INTO service_service_categories (service_id,service_category_id) SELECT service_id, category_id FROM ins1
      )
      select * from ins1
      `,
      [name, summary, category_id]
    );
```

But the problem is I want to be able to return an ARRAY of integers ie category_ids rather than just a single integer (because each service can have multiple categories).

How should I do this using node? I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
// Create a service
router.post('/', async( req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { name, summary, category_ids } = req.body;
    const newService = await pool.query(
      `
      with ins1 AS
      (
       INSERT INTO services (name,summary,category_ids)
           VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING service_id, category_ids
      ),
      ins2 AS
      (
         CREATE FUNCTION loopCateg() RETURNS integer AS $$
         DECLARE @i INT
         BEGIN
         WHILE @i < category_ids
         INSERT INTO service_service_categories (service_id,service_category_id) SELECT service_id, category_ids FROM ins1
           @i := @i + 1;
         END loop;
         END;
         $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
      )
      SELECT * FROM ins1
      `,
      [name, summary, category_ids]
    );

    res.json(newService);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
})
```

Comment: You can't use `create function` inside a common table expression (`WITH` statement). And the syntax you are using is completely wrong anyway)

Comment: Thanks for telling me it is the wrong approach. Could you explain what I SHOULD do?

Comment: To be more explicit in what I want to know: 
1. How do I do a function in a node-postgres query? 
2. Can you do while loop through array returned from another insert?

Please point me to example code.

Comment: By the way in case you wanted to know the answer, and anyone else who struggles to find the answer to what should be a fairly simple thing, it is by using transactions https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions